# How to direct the result of mongoquery to a file

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to send the result of mongo query to a file using mongo shell. I had used this following command.

```
 C:\>mongodb\bin\mongo localhost/mydb –eval "db.docs.count()" >> counttest.txt
```

Actually my text file got created with this stack trace.

```
 2016-05-13T12:35:51.485+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
    MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
    connecting to: localhost/mydb
    loading file: –eval
    2016-05-13T12:35:51.541+0530 E -        [main] file [–eval] doesn't exist
    failed to load: –eval
```

With `--eval`, I'm facing this error:

```
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '-ΓÇôeval' try 'mongo --help' for more information
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue?

Comment: With --eval,I'm facing this error:Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '-ΓÇôeval'
try 'mongo --help' for more information

Comment: I had fixed my error by using this command :C:\>mongodb\bin\mongo localhost:27017/mydb –-eval "db.docs.count()" >> counttest.txt